# QGIS: multiple mosaics bands to 1 Visual RGB

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, rgb, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pix4d

I have UAV raster converted with Pix4D mapper in transparents mosaics blue, green, red, nir, pir.

Which tool can I use to translate into a visual RGB image?

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a Virtual Raster. Make sure to check `Place each input file into a separate band`

[image]